# Hiding/Showing UITableViewCell Accessory Disclosure Indicator

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to load a string from Core Data and if that value in that row equals to "--" the Accessory Disclosure Indicator will hide and the cell selection style should be `SelectionStyleNone`.

I tried this, but not successful

```
if (entity.value == @"--"){
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Or

```
NSString *this = entity.value;
if (this == @"--") {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Neither are working, but is this possible though? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that the problem is on the comparison expression. The correct way:

```
if ([entity.value isEqualToString:@"--"])
```

or

```
if ([this isEqualToString:@"--"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use:

```
if ([userEventStatus.status.stringValue isEqual:@"--"])
```

It might seem like a subtle change but using the *isEqual* instead of *isEqualToString* means that if your code is more robust if you change the type of data going through it (intValue, floatValue, CGPointValue). Instead of having to rewrite the entire function you can just change the entered variable.

This type of method can also be easily copied to different parts of an app and the value changed depending on the circumstances.